# Using SizeToFit() to Top Align UILabel Causes Jumping

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

The following code works to vertically align text in a UILabel to the top-left of the view box. However, it causes the text to jump back and forth between proper vertical top alignment and vertical centering. The cadence of it's jumping seems to be about that of the location update rate.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    var userlocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userlocation, completionHandler: {
        (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if( error != nil )
        {
            println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if( placemarks.count > 0 )
        {
            let placeMark = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
            self.nearestAddressLabel.text = ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(placeMark.addressDictionary, false);

            self.nearestAddressLabel.sizeToFit()
        }
        else
        {
            println("No placemarks!")
        }

    })
}
```

GIF of problem: https://imgflip.com/gif/m82jf

Any idea how I can avoid this infernal jumping around?

Comment: Why is the address changing so often? Can you control that?

Comment: Is the `UILabel` frame ever too big for the text? You can see this easily if you temporarily set the label's `backgroundColor` to `UIColor.purpleColor()`

Comment: Also is your label created in a storyboard?

Comment: @MichaelL: It's changing as fast as the location is being updated. The app is trying to display the nearest address. It's just a test / learning app.

Comment: @Dash The label is created in a storyboard, yes. Your background color tip was illuminating - it looks like what's happening is my sizeToFit() call is resizing the label to fit around the text, but for some reason each time it jumps it looks like the label is getting bigger (to match the size I have in the storyboard) and the text fails to properly vertical align top when it's in that state.

Comment: @Dash https://imgflip.com/gif/mf8ui

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE:

If you are using storyboard and auto layout you should not use the `sizeToFit()`. `sizeToFit()` is part of the "old" way, pre Auto Layout, and will not behave as expected if Storyboard uses any `Constraints`.

Instead in Interface Builder:

- Set *Lines* to 0 (Allow many lines)
- Position the label as needed using any *Constraints*
- Add a fixed *Constraint* for *width*
- Add a *Contraints* for *height* using *Less Than or Equal*

This will make sure the position is correct, and allow for the Auto Layout to resize the UILabels height as needed when content is updated.

[image]

UPDATE 2:

Not entirely sure why I got down voted, as the suggested answer works.
In this example, I am using a timer to update my label, see result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is in essence what I've done, though instead of specifying the frame through code I've done that in the storyboard. Is there any reason that approach wouldn't work?